# calculate or save spatial data

Tags: postgis

When working with spatial data in a data base like Postgis, is it a good way to calculate on every SELECT the intersections of two polygons or the area of polygons? Or is it better for performance issues to do the calculations on an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE-statement and save the results in a column of the tables? How is the approach in big spatial data bases?

Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The questuion is too abstract.

Of course if you use the intersection area (`ST_Intersection`) you should store the result of `ST_Intersection` geometry. But in practice we often have to calculate intersection on-fly, because entrance arguments depend on dynamical parameters (e.g. intersection of an area with temperature <30C with and area of wind > 20 ms). By the way you can use VIEW to simplify a query in that way.

Of course if your table contains both geometrical column-arguments or one of them is constant it's better to store the intersection. Particularly you can build spatial indexes for this column.

There is no any constant rules. You should be guided by practice conditions: size of database, type of using etc. For example I store the generated ellipse (belief zone) for point of lightning stroke, but I don't store facts of intersectioning (boolean) with powerlines because those intersetionings may be parametrized.